# Altering height of Bootstrap panel footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the height of Bootstrap's panel footer to make it shorter, however after looking around everywhere I haven't found a way to do that whilst also adjusting the position of the text within the footer, so that it doesn't poke out the bottom.

(Merely adjusting the font size obviously wasn't enough)

Here is my code and a screenshot of my issue:

```
.panel-default>.panel-footer {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-size: smaller;
    max-height: 20px;
}

<div class="panel-footer">
    (0 comments)
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAXX8.jpg

Comment: It's hard to tell from your snippet, what is actually wrong. Maybe it's `max-height: 20px;`, maybe you're missing `clearfix`. Add more details to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quas94** Hi there.
All you need to do here to change the height of the panel footer is this with some css.

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oet6aosm/)**.

```
.panel-heading{
    height:50px;
} 
.panel-body{
    min-height:150px; 
    background-color: gray;
}     
.panel-footer{
    height:100px; 
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, it worked - I had tried just using the height attribute earlier but it didn't work.

Seemed like it was because I was targeting .panel-default>.panel-footer
instead of just .panel-footer.

Do you think you can explain why that is? Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Hi there, Depends on the editor you may be using. If you tried it this way and it did not work. It may need to re load or even save and reload in the browser. As you can see you just need to change the height directly to the `panel-footer` class. Glad it is working for you now.